# Text highlighting for ES6 template literals (backticks) in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, webstorm, backticks, template-literals

Where should I look in the settings to remove the green background highlighting for text within the backticks? I think it is related to HTML in non-HTML files, probably it has nothing to do with quotes or backticks. I've been searching through settings the best I could.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I'll let this stay in case anyone else wonders.

Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General -> Injected language fragment -> Uncheck background on the right side panel

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 2):

... and for some reason they've changed this again in 2017.2

Now go to Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Injected language fragment and uncheck "Background"

Answer (score 1):

**In 2019.3:**

**`Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Code > Injected language fragment`**

And deselect **`Background`**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For v 2017.1 and up it's Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General > Code > Injected language fragment > uncheck **Background**

Comment: In 2018.2.1 there is no "Editor > Colors & Fonts". They keep moving stuff around.